# How to judge a column is auto increment？

Tags: h2

I usually use Mysql： INFORMATION_SCHEMA -> COLUMNS -> EXTRA -> auto_increment

I didn't find the EXTRA field in COLUMNS of System Tables

Is there any good way to get it？

appreciate you！

https://h2database.com/html/systemtables.html

Answer (score 0):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is a feature of MySQL and possibly some others. H2 accepts this clause for a some limited compatibility, but its implementation in H2 is entirely different.

In 1.4.200 you need to check `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_DEFAULT` for a `NEXT VALUE FOR …` expression.

In upcoming H2 2.0 this column will have `NULL` value for identity columns just like for many other columns. You will need to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.IS_IDENTITY` instead, its value is `YES` for identity columns and `NO` for others.